# Was the Batman / Green Hornet crossover the first filmed Bruce Lee fight?

Tags: cinema-history, bruce-lee

The IMDB entry for [Burt Ward](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0911431/bio?ref_=nm_ov_bio_sm) states:

> A special piece of movie trivia is that Bruce Lee's first filmed fight scene of his career was fighting Burt Ward.

This seems a bit off to me since *The Green Hornet* first aired in 1966, and the crossover episode was in 1967. Is it true that this was his first filmed fight?

Comment: IMDB lists a number of non-US movies before that but what Lee's role is not listed. Quite possibly accurate.

Comment: There's a bit more filmography info at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bruce_Lee_filmography, but a decent amount of it seems to be no action rolled before 1966.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to say that this is an exaggeration, whether by the studios or possibly promulgated by Burt Ward himself. The first episode of *The Green Hornet*, "[The Silent Gun](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0592841/?ref_=ttloc_loc_tt)", aired on the 9th of September, 1966, and had Lee, as Kato, fighting some henchmen. That clearly predates the *Batman* episode, "[A Piece of the Action](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0519447/)", from the 1st of March, 1967, where Robin and Kato fought.

Unless there's some other qualifier to the statement, or special circumstances, such as Burt Ward and Bruce Lee having had a formerly filmed fight (by some accounts, they were neighbors and had sparred before) before the episode, this claim is false.